# What does 「選挙を追った」 mean here?

Tags: meaning, verbs, word-usage

> 選挙カーも走らない静かな選挙戦だったが、投票率は何と８９・４１％。
>
> 飛び地の村の不思議な**選挙を追った**。

Source: https://www.sankei.com/premium/news/191209/prm1912090002-n1.html

An enclave town with a quiet election campaign without any cars running had a voter turnout of a whopping 89.41% following the somewhat strange election.

I haven't seen 追う used like this before. Can I translate the 「選挙を追った」part as "following".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「追{お}う」 here means "***to observe and analyze***" or just "***to investigate***".  The verb is frequently used for that meaning in news coverage, documentaries, etc.

To use a stiff expression, 「追う」 here means "to inquire into the truth of the matter".

IMHO, "to follow" would be too weak a translation for the context.

[Weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E8%BF%BD%E3%81%86) gives "to observe" as one of the definitions.

Comment: Thank you so much :D